# Generate traffic and measure qos parameters in custom mininet topology using Ryu Controller

Tags: mininet, openflow, qos, iperf, ryu

I'm working on tweaking and testing QoS capabilities in SDN. I've tried POX and Ryu controller and run some custom topologies in mininet. However I need help for generating traffic in mininet topology. It seems that there are iperf and D-ITG for this purpose. I couldn't find much about D-ITG and little about iperf. Specifically I'm very interested to find out how we can measure qos parameters like throughput or latency in a custom mininet topology like a basic datacenter, in the following link, you can find such basic data center topology using ryu controller:
[custom mininet topology-basic data center](https://inside-openflow.com/2016/06/29/custom-mininet-topologies-and-introducing-atom/)

So, please let me know if you know how to generate traffic in mininet, different kinds of traffic if possible, like video or game data, and increase or tweak the load on different links and observe the controller behavior in rerouting the flows